# shell script to move a set of folders into one folder and timestamp it

Tags: bash, scripts, directory, timestamp

I have a set of folders (let's assume at `/home/20161`, `/home/20162`, `/home/20163`) which have been timestamped already. at the end of the day, I'd like to collect all of them and move to a main directory, timestamped, at the same path (`/home/Main(date of today`) including the aforementioned folders) using a shell script.

How can I do this?

Any kind of help is appreciate it

I use this script to time stamp the files into separate folders but don't know how to continue it for folders:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/sina/Desktop/Recordings/

shopt -s nullglob  # this line is so that it does not compain when no  logfiles are found
for filename in Screen.mkv; do # Files considered are the ones startign with test and ending in .log
foldername=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S); # Create Folder based on date of time of recording
mkdir -p "$foldername"  # -p so that we dont get "folder exists" warning
mv "$filename" "$foldername"
echo "$filename $foldername" ;

done
for filename in Webcam.mp4; do
    mv "$filename" "$foldername"
    echo "$filename $foldername";

done
```

Comment: Um . . . why do you create directories in `/home` ? It's typically for user's personal directories , not for storing files.   Also, this is a very simple question. Have you tried anything by yourself so far ? Why or why not ?

Comment: I updated the post, I do this for the files but afterwards I'd like to do the same for the created directories

Comment: `/home/` was just an example. the right path is included in updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mv` command has `-t` flag , synonym for `--target-directory=DIRNAME`.

```
 -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
              move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

Basic idea is that you can specify destination to all the items, like so: `mv -t DESTINATION ITEM1 ITEM2  ITEM3. . .`

So the two step process would be create the Main timestamped directory  `Main_$DATE` and then `mv` all the folders you want. Like so,

```
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir$ DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir$ mkdir Main_$DATE
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir$ ls
20161  20162  20163  Main_20160109_114336
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir$ mv -t Main_20160109_114336/ 20161/ 20162/ 20163/ 
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir$ ls 
Main_20160109_114336
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir$ ls Main_20160109_114336/
20161  20162  20163
```

Of course you could put everything into a small script or even a bash function inside `.bashrc`. Something like

```
function collectStuff 
{
  CENTRALDIR="/home/sina/Desktop/Recordings"
  DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)

  MAIN="$CENTRALDIR"/"Main_$DATE"
   mv -t "$MAIN"  "$@"

}
```

`"$@"` will expand all the command line argumens, so that way you could run something like `collectStuff dirname1 dirname2 dirname3`

Comment: Great! it worked like a charm! thanks a lot :-)